# Creating permanent-alias bash command

Tags: linux, bash, sh, alias

I am trying to create a "permalias" bash command to be able to easily create permanent aliases without having to directly work on the ~/.bashrc file.

As of now, the only way I've been able to make this work is with this code:

```
alias permalias="echo alias $1 >> ~/.bashrc"
```

which allows for an input in this format:

```
permalias commandname=\"commandbody\"
```

But I am not satisfied with this because I'd like to mantain a simpler input format, one closer to the original alias command's.

I tried several variants of this code:

```
alias permalias="echo alias $1=\"$2\" >> ~/.bashrc"
```

Using this version, this code `permalias c "echo test"` should add this line `alias permalias c="echo test"` to the ~/.bashrc file.

But instead this is the result: `alias c "echo test"`, which, of course, does not work.

I'd also be grateful for any advice on how to avoid the need of putting the " around the new command's body.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
permalias()
{
  local alias_regex='[A-Za-z_0-9]*'
  if
    [[ $# = 1 && $1 =~ ($alias_regex)=(.*) ]]
  then
    printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}=\"${BASH_REMATCH[2]}\"" >> ~/.bashrc
  else
    echo "USAGE: permalias VARNAME=ALIAS_COMMAND"
    return 1
  fi
}
```

A nicer version would check for the presence of said alias in `.bashrc` first, and would then replace it or fail if it is already present.

Comment: Thank you! I enhanced your solution, renamed the function to `aka` and published the snippet as a Gist: https://gist.github.com/Khazbs/923dea22873cee84a6a0ba25a2d7de36

Answer (score 0):

You can't use arguments in an `alias`. What you need is a function, something like:

```
permalias() {
    echo "alias ${1}=\"${2}\"" >> ~/.bashrc
}
```

Comment: Tried it, the result is the same. The = is not written in the file. Also what is the meaning of the { } around the arguments' number?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function as Olli says, then you could use `"$*"` to concatenate all the arguments to the function.

```
permalias() { 
    n=$1; 
    shift; 
    echo "alias $n=\"$*\"" >> ~/.bashrc; 
}
```

This should work with stuff like `permalias c echo foo bar`, but if you actually want quotes *inside* the alias, it will get hairy. `permalias c echo "foo     bar"` would not work, you'd need something like `permalias c echo "'foo     bar'"` to counter the additional level of command line processing and get the inside quotes to the file.

For anything complicated, it's better to make a shell function anyway. You can use `declare -fp funcname` to print the definition of a function, and save it to a file if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use zsh, drawing on Fred's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319680/8398127), we can switch $BASH-REMATCH for $match and send the aliases to .zsh_aliases (assuming you have them set up-- if not add .zsh_aliases to your homedir and add this to your .zshrc: `source ~/.zsh_aliases`).

So, as an example, I added this function to my .zsh_aliases file and it works well.

```
 permalias() {
    sauce="unhash -ma "*" ; unhash -mf "*"; source ~/.zshrc"
    local alias_regex='[A-Za-z_0-9]*'
    if
        [[ $# == 1 && $1 =~ ($alias_regex)=(.*) ]]
    then
        printf "%s\n" "alias ${match[1]}=\"${match[2]}\"" >>~/.zsh_aliases
        #uncomment the following line to automatically load your new alias
        #eval ${sauce}
    else
        echo "Usage: permalias ALIAS_NAME=ALIAS_COMMAND"
        return 1
    fi
}
```